# Injective object in the category of rings

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

Does category of commutative rings with 1 have injective objects? 
I did the exercise that category of abelian groups have divisible groups as injective objective, but I have no idea about rings.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is injective in the category of rings with identity.

Comment: Can you give complete answer to my question?

Comment: I think a complete answer would be more descriptive about what other injective rings are out there, but I also don't know anything about them. I have also had the same question, but I've never seen anyone interested in it in the literature. I just wanted to make sure you knew the obvious example. If you like, you can take my comment and self-answer.